# single instead of double select statement

Tags: php, mysql

first table - `bplus` - has a column named `home01` with values identical to some values in column `fname` of table `banners`

```
$items = '';
$sql = "select home01 from bplus";
$st = $db->query($sql);
$arr = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
foreach ($arr as $el){
    $el = trim($el);
    $sqlb = "select * from banners where fname = '" . $el . "'";
    $stb = $db->query($sqlb);
    $row = $stb->fetch();
    $items .= "<img class='itemtop' src = '../banners/" . $el . "' alt='img' data-id = " . $row['id'] . " data-fname = '" . $row['fname'] . ">\n"; 
}
echo $items;
```

this works but probably there is a shorter way, with a single `select` statement.

Any help?

Comment: Yes. Use `WHERE fname in ($el1, $el2)` (same as using `OR`)

Comment: @Justinas, could you write entire line, pls. Because count of `el1`, `el2`... is not the same each time. I'm not sure what you're thinking.

Comment: Are you looking for a [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) query…?

Comment: @deceze, probably yes.

Comment: This answer is not relevant to your question but you are using an sql statement whitout preparing it (sqlb). That's a huge vulnerability and can be exploited. For example changing el into DROP TABLE injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [LEFT JOIN](http://LEFT%20JOIN)

```
select bplus.home01, banners.* from bplus left join banners on bplus.home01 = banners.fname;
```

Comment: `bplus`.id is not equal to `banners.id`. Also I need all column values from `banners`.

Comment: you can put any field name which is belongs to banner

Comment: you can give the fields name in query for selecting many fields or all

Comment: ok, I see. What about `where bplus.id = banners.id`. ID is not the same

Comment: it doesn't work. My values from `bplus` are COLUMN values - not a ROW values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169146/discussion-between-rahul-shrivastava-and-puerto).

Comment: why left join the same table when ids are different? seems inefficient?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs id is different but  you can see here select home01 from bplus he selects home01 from first table and after iteration he selects select * from banners where fname = '" . $el . "' that means $el=home01 so bplus.home01==banners.fname

Comment: glad to help you